# Make a preview render for a piece of the video in Kdenlive

Tags: kdenlive

Kdenlive normally makes preview renders in real time (just by pressing space). The thing is; my computer isn't powerful so Kdenlive keeps dropping frames just to keep the preview real time. The preview looks awful.

I used to use adobe premier. It had another way to preview. You could just render a piece of the video before previewing it (by pressing zero on the numeric keypad) and then press again preview it without having to drop frames.

Is it possible in some way to do that in Kdenlive?

...well if not, does anyone know a workaround?

Answer (score 2):

You could just press Render (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>) anyway - removing the 2 pass option, and reducing the video and audio bitrate should make it a bit quicker:

[image: Kdenlive Render Window]

Selecting 'play after render' may help as well, it will open the finished video in the video player set for that format in KDE's System Settings (e.g. MPlayer)

There sadly does not seem to be anything under 'Settings' > 'Configure Shortcuts' that could be used to set a shortcut to export a preview.

---

**Edit:** this might solve your problem:
[image: Press the settings button beneath the preview and de-select 'Real-time (drop frames)']

Answer (score 0):

In Render settings there is an option "Selected zone" in the bottom part. This allows to render only that part and not whole project.